# pickleファイルを読み込もうとした際に発生したEOFErrorについて

Tags: python

## Overview

---

行おうとしたことを簡単に書きます：

1. pd.DataFrameに入ったテキストデータをsentence transfomerに入力し，sentence embeddingを得る．
2. そのsentence embeddingをemb_listというlist型にappend()で追加．
3. そのlistをpickle.dump()でpickleファイルに保存
4. そのpickleファイルを読み込もうとpickle.load()で読み込み

4.を実行すると`EOFError: Ran out of input`が発生．

## Details

---

ここから詳細に入りますが，その前にDataFrameの準備から：

```
from urllib.request import urlretrieve
import pandas as pd

# Download the parquet table
table_url = f'https://huggingface.co/datasets/poloclub/diffusiondb/resolve/main/metadata.parquet'
urlretrieve(table_url, 'metadata.parquet')

# Read the table using Pandas
df_2m = pd.read_parquet('metadata.parquet')
```

df_2m['prompt']の各行には，次のようにstr型のオブジェクトが入っています：

```
1          a portrait of a female robot made from a cloud...
2              only memories remain, trending on artstation 
3                           dream swimming pool with nobody 
4                   a dog doing weights. epic oil painting. 
                                 ...                        
1999995    david bowie giving a piggy back ride to ziggy ...
1999996    david bowie giving a piggy back ride to ziggy ...
1999997                                      funny computer 
1999998                   hilarious witty computing machine 
1999999     hilarious witty computing machine, lichtenstien 
Name: prompt, Length: 2000000, dtype: object
```

以下，行おうとしたこと1～3：

```
import sys
from sentence_transformers import SentenceTransformer, models

# pathの追加
sys.path.append('./sentence-transformers-2-2-2/sentence-transformers')

# sentence transformerの読み込み
st_model = SentenceTransformer('./sentence-transformers-2-2-2/all-MiniLM-L6-v2')

emb_list = []
for i, row in df_2m.iterrows():
    # 1.sentence embeddingを出力
    emb = st_model.encode(row['prompt'])
    # 2. sentence embeddingをemb_listに追加
    emb_list.append(emb)
    if ((i+1) % 1000)==0:
        print(f'Saved at {i+1} prompts.')
        # 3. pickleファイルに保存
        with open('./SD2GPT2/2M/embedding_2M_0.pickle', 'wb') as f:
            pickle.dump(emb_list, f)
```

4.pickleファイルの読み込み：

```
with open('./SD2GPT2/2M/embedding_2M_0.pickle', 'rb') as f:
    print(f)
    emb_list0 = pickle.load(f)
```

読み込めず，エラー：

```
╭─────────────────────────────── Traceback (most recent call last) ────────────────────────────────╮
│ in <module>                                                                                      │
│                                                                                                  │
│   1 with open('./SD2GPT2/2M/embedding_2M_0.pickle', 'rb') as f:                                  │
│ ❱ 2 │   emb_list1 = pickle.load(f)                                                               │
│   3                                                                                              │
╰──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────╯
EOFError: Ran out of input
```

## Question

---

ファイルが空でないことは確認しました．

- なぜこのエラーが発生したのか
- どうすれば読み込めるようになるか

をお教えください．

## P.S.

---

1000行だけ，次に10000行だけ，そして100000行だけでファイルへの保存と読み込みを行ったところ，読み込みができるようになりました．
データ量のせい？もしくは何か他に原因がある？
pickleの仕様をあとで調べてみます．

Comment: 試しに Colabで実行してみたところ Saved at 596000 prompts.まで進みました(`pickle.dump` 直後に `pickle.load` で確認するよう変更したもの)。RAM使用量が 10GBを超え限界に近づいたため停止。もしかすると(そのように)何らかのリソース不足で不安定になったのでは？

Comment: Lib/pickleのDocumentを読んでみましたが原因が分からず．

Comment: >oririさん そうかもしれないですね．はっきりとした原因が分かればまた書きます．応急処置として，同様のことを行う際は「大容量のデータをpickleファイルに1つに保存せず，小分けすると難なく読み込める」としておきます．